# Can the firebase-messaging-sw.js location be changed from the app root, or hide its key? as SENDER_ID key is exposed / public

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am newbie using Firebase and now working on setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging for a web client app (using vue js).

Everything works perfect as expected: I receive push notifications and so on. However I'm concerned that the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** (service worker for receiving notifications in the Background) contains the **SENDER_ID** and is publicly exposed on the root folder (I tried to change the file location but doesn't work, firebase docs says must be be in the root folder in order to work),

firebase.initializeApp({ 'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR-SENDER-ID' });

**Is there any way of hiding this key, or placing this file in my app src folder?**

Comment: If you are asking about securing your data, take a look at [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: Thank you @Jay for your reply, I am actually referring to the Firebase Cloud Messaging where is being used a service worker firebase-messaging-sw.js for receiving notifications in a web client in Background. The issue comes that this file is public and in the config line contains the SENDER_ID and I am concerned about this key being exposed.Hope this makes more sense. Thanks.                                                                                                                                        firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR-SENDER-ID'
});

Comment: i'm having the same issue..@jf._